# why people are defining data type in php?

Tags: php

Hi friends why people are defining data type in php as below,

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: *(reference)* [TypeCasting](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting)

Answer (score 4):

To make sure the variable really contains a valid number. For example, empty string will be converted to 0, 'abc' will be converted to 0, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This assigns the value of the URL parameter `"id"` (converted to an integer) to the variable `$id`. The parameters in the URL are of course strings, therefore if you pass an integer this way you first should cast it to the int datatype.

Comment: Well, you don't have to. php `"5" + "6" == 11`.

Comment: You don't have to, but it still is good practice. And you anyway have to check if the id is valid, and that is much easier if it is an int.

Answer (score 1):

Because that way you know what you are manipulating so there is no surprise.